# Do not copy domain model when duplicating page

Tags: typo3, domain-model, extbase

We have an Extbase extension which has a domain model associated with tt_content elements. When we delete a page or content element, all domain model items associated are also deleted. This is good and we want that behaviour (otherwise we would leave orphans behind).

But our client wishes that the items from this domain model are not duplicated when the page is duplicated. Is there a way to tell TYPO3 to not duplicate the domain model items of this extension during copy actions?

**Edit:** We are using TYPO3 4.5 in this project.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle this is to add the table of the model to the "not-allowed" section, but this will also remove the ability to modify the backend-datasets everywhere.

Here is why (in TYPO3 6.0):

File:method: \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::copyPages

```php
$copyTablesArray = $this->admin ? $this->compileAdminTables() : explode(',', $this->BE_USER->groupData['tables_modify']);
// If not all tables are allowed then make a list of allowed tables: That is the tables that figure in both allowed tables AND the copyTable-list
if (!strstr($this->copyWhichTables, '*')) {
    foreach ($copyTablesArray as $k => $table) {
        // Pages are always going...
        if (!$table || !\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::inList(($this->copyWhichTables . ',pages'), $table)) {
            unset($copyTablesArray[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

All Tables that are set in `$copyTablesArray` will be copied. They are set in `$this->BE_USER->groupData['tables_modify']` if the current logged in user is not an admin.

Maybe adding a alternative implementation of this method can handle this, but this a not very easy way.

Comment: In Rails I would do it in an after_create hook in the model or an object observer which triggers on copy and simply clear the has_many association before the object is persisted. Is there something similar in TYPO3? The TYPO3 version in question is 4.5, not 6.0. I already figured there are some differences. BTW: The datasets are not modified in the backend but proxied to another framework which handles editing of these datasets because TYPO3 was too slow to do it (30s and more per backend page load)...